# Default/System Android Processes

Tags: android, process

I am currently working on an Android project that monitors what applications a user is running and cross-checks the corresponding processes with a whitelist stored internally on the device.

In order to make this work, I need to know what the default or system processes for the device are so I can add them to the whitelist.  That being said, I have a few questions I was hoping you might be able to answer:

1. Is there a way to differentiate between a default/system process that MUST be running, and a process that belongs to an app on the device?
2. Are there different default/system processes depending on what phone/version of android the user is running?
3. If so, are those process names available somewhere for developer use?  Or is there some other way to obtain them?

If I need to elaborate more please let me know, thanks for the help.

Comment: "Are there different default/system processes depending on what phone/version of android the user is running?" -- yes. Each device manufacturer is welcome to do what they want. "If so, are those process names available somewhere for developer use?" -- I doubt it, simply because there are thousands of Android device models, each of which could have a different mix of "default/system" processes at its manufacturer's discretion.

Comment: Hmm...  that's an issue.  Do you know anything about my first question then?  If there is a way to make a discretion between default/system processes and processes belonging to downloaded applications?

Comment: I haven't looked into it. I am skeptical that you will be able to come up with something that is reliable across the pantheon of possibilities.

Comment: Darn, that's unfortunate.  The project  I'm managing is aimed at allowing students to use their mobile devices in class, for tests and lecture.  We had the idea that by monitoring which applications were running on the phone, we would be able to display to the teacher via a GUI if the students were using their devices properly and not cheating.  But it seems like from what you've said it will be nearly impossible to execute.  If you have any suggestions though I'd really be interested, you have a lot more experience than my team or I.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you'd have other problems besides the ones you ask about. You have no way of constructing a useful blacklist, for example, and a whitelist is tantamount to simply banning the devices. Bear in mind that processes can be started for background operations (e.g., data synchronization), so simply scanning running processes for whitelist violations will mean ~100% of devices will violate. Not to mention the privacy implications of what you are describing.

Comment: If we had a whitelist however, a black list would not be necessary.  An assumption would be made that everything NOT on the whitelist is not allowed.  I'm not sure what you mean by banning the devices (EDIT:  just read your edit, I understand now), but we wouldn't be physically stopping anyone from doing anything.  Rather, all we would do is monitor what is running and let the consequences fall to the discretion of the teacher.  The privacy is something we are well aware of also, there would need to be consent from students and teachers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think my team and I have come up with the best solution so far.  After reading the Android Docs, we found that by using `ActivityManager.getRunningServices()` we can use the constant `FLAG_SYSTEM_PROCESS` to determine what processes are core system processes.  Then all we would do is cross-check that with the total list of running processes to differentiate between them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you try `ActivityManager` and `getRunningAppProcesses()`. Iterate over that array of `RunningAppProcessInfo` objects and find those with `importance` of `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`. If the docs are correct (haven't tried this), there should only be one process that is `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` -- the one that is truly in the UI foreground.

(services can call a `startForeground()` method to get foreground priority, but I am guessing they have `IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE`)

You could then examine the `pkgList` of that foreground process and compare that against your whitelist.

However, this breaks down if:

- Something pops up asynchronously (alarm clock app, incoming phone call, etc.)
- An app that is logically in your whitelist has changes that affect its package name (e.g., developer released a "pro" app that a student paid for, and the whitelist only has the free app)
- if the device has multiple visible items (e.g., Samsung's multi-window capabilities), if all visible apps are not `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`

This at least gets rid of the problem of pure background stuff that the student cannot control, including your "default/system processes".

However, it requires you to continuously poll, which will be a serious detriment to battery life. That, plus the privacy implications, means to me that this app should, at best, only be used for exams, and should be something that the student can install shortly before the exam and remove shortly after the exam.

Comment: It's funny you mention the importance aspect, I was just reading the docs for that myself.  I was already using ActivityManager and getRunningAppProcesses(), perhaps my team will be able to use that somehow.  Though you're also very correct in all the exceptions that come up.  That's why I was initially asking about default processes and what not, because even though we could easily get the processes associated with each application a specific teacher wants to allow, there are so many different devices out there that it becomes very difficult.

Comment: Here's something interesting that I've found, I was wondering if you'd have any input.  What if instead of using processes, we used tasks instead?  Using ActivityManager we could try getRunningTasks().  Then instead of RunningAppProcessInfo, we could use RunningTaskInfo.

Comment: @AaronStephens: I recommend that you read the JavaDocs for `getRunningTasks()`. That being said, I know some people are trying to use the first entry out of `getRunningTasks()` to determine what the foreground app is, but that has all the same problems as are in my bulleted list above (with slight tweaks to the third bullet), and it still requires you to poll.